# Web of Science; any way to get the "Published Items in Each Year" numeric data?

Tags: website, bibliometrics

If you perform a search in Web of Science there is an option to create a "citation report";
[image: click to create a citation report]

This provides charts of citations each year, and the number of papers published each year;
[image]
Is there any way I can get the numbers used to draw the "Published Items in Each Year" graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't *think* this is possible in WoS without pulling each paper's citation data and assembling it manually, and I don't think you want to do that!

It is possible to do this with Scopus, however:

- select all search results
- "view cited by"
- filter by year

Note, however, that citation numbers in Web of Science and Scopus are *not* directly comparable, as Scopus indexes many more items. So if you were to use this, you'd want to make sure all your data came from the same source.

Comment: After poking WoS for some time I'm inclined to agree with you on it not being possible.

Comment: Followed your advice, Scopus will give lots more numeric data. Thanks